# Screen layout doesn't look good on bigger screens

Tags: android

I have 3 horizontal LinearLayouts, I've been making xml on 4.7 screen and it looked good, then i switched to bigger screen and it doesnt look good. So my xml looks good on screen size of 4.7 but on 10.01 and 7 it screws up
on 4.7 screen:
[image]

on 10,01 :[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroun"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
  >

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:text="Load" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Play"
         android:layout_weight="1" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Mute" 
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Volume up"
         android:layout_weight="1" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button5"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Volume up"
         android:layout_weight="1" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button6"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Mute" 
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button7"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Play"
         android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button8"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Load"
         android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="7"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_weight="7"/>

    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

         <SeekBar
             android:id="@+id/seekBar3"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1" />

         <SeekBar
             android:id="@+id/seekBar4"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Refer these links. 

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you use `android:layout_weight` you should set the `android:layout_width="0dp"`
Besides that now, I would suggest having a separate layout for xlarge screens. 
The way to do that is to create a separate folder that will contain a layout with the same name as your original layout (eg. main.xml). The folder name for 10" screens should be something like `layout-xlarge`. 
For more details you should check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 1):

For different size screens. you can also make another layout for bigger screen.

res/layout-small  
res/layout-large  
res/layout-xlarge

create a new folder as named "layout-xlarge" and copy your xml layout in there and you can adjust the sizes.

Android will automatically select the appropriate layout for the current device. Remember that, layout name should be the same in each folder.